# Check if behavior is attached to element

Tags: d3.js

The question is: how to check if the d3 behavior, such as drag or zoom, is already called on the element? Seems to be this task is in relation to getting the events, which are attached to element? What is the common approach?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think D3 allows you to check this easily, but it generally doesn't hurt to attach a behaviour twice -- the event handlers will simply be overwritten.

Comment: Hi again, Lars) I have complicated logic with combined brush and zoom behaviors at one chart so it is pain to remember/assign to vars all scales/extents and so on, it is much easier and cleaner to check if an element already has behavior in my case.

Comment: Could you assign the behaviours after everything is set up?

Comment: I'm with Lars. Don't think there's a built in way. But you can explicitly give elements classes or data attributes to mark whether they have a particular behavior. Like `if(!sel.classed("zoomable")) { sel.classed("zoomable", true).call(zoomBehavior); }`.

Comment: That's the point, @meetamit - there is no direct way. Solution similar to 'zoomable' class is implemented now, but presence of 'zoomable' class doesn't guarantee that element really has behavior attached.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I came across this post looking for the same thing, saw there wasn't an answer, so created the answer my self. This is for d3.js Version 4.

```
function hasD3EventOn(ele, eventName, eventType) {
    if (!ele || typeof eventName == 'undefined') return !1;
    if (ele._groups) ele = ele._groups[0][0]; // if d3.select()
    var on = ele.__on; //d3.js(v4) function onRemove(typename)
    if (!on || !on.length) return !1; var i = on.length, o;
    while (--i >= 0) { if ((o = on[i]).name && o.name === eventName && (typeof eventType == 'undefined' || (o.type && o.type === eventType))) return !0; } return !1;
}
```

Just send in either a d3.select element (first in array only) or a native DOM Element along with the event name such as 'zoom', both are reqired. There is also the option for the event type such as 'wheel'. It also has some basic validation (maybe excessive) to help prevent crashing when called with trash or property name collison.